# Embedded Video creating bugs for position:fixed top header

Tags: css, youtube-api, frame, css-position

I have a menu element on the top of the page with

```
position:fixed;
z-index:1000;
```

and it normally stays at the top of the page, without any complaining.  However, whenever I have a youtube embedded video in the page (also must be playing at the time) it seems, the fixed menu has all sorts of glitches and jumping around.  Is this a common issue, embedded videos interfering with position:fixed elements?  The issue is in Chrome, Safari, but oddly enough, not in Firefox.

Does this console error have anything to do with it?
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ww.youtube... from frame with URL ww.youtube... Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I know this description is not very elaborate, so here is the url: [Chronicle Video Section](http://www.hwchronicle.com/video/).  I'm making my high school's school newspaper site, and I'm stumped on this one issue - never seen it before.  Try scrolling up and down while the video is playing.  Thanks for your help.

The div the iframe is in is:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>
        <iframe... />
    </p>
</div>
```

If it helps, how I have it set up is that it currently pulls the entry content of the wordpress post content which is just the youtube url and Wordpress converts the url into an embed into that div.

Comment: This question is not about programming embedded systems. Retagged.

Comment: try to share the css of the video or the div containing it also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a YouTube bug.  This is a webkit bug related to redrawing of fixed position items.  I recommending filing the bug with webkit.
http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html

If you want a work around for now, I would recommend listening to the window scroll event and changing the style of the menu(width, height, or position) to force a redraw.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was going crazy.  Will most likely set position: absolute to workaround.

Answer (score 13):

I found that adding the style rules

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

to the fixed element sorted out the craziness for me.

Comment: If anyone can provide explanation for how this sorcery works, that'd be nice, but otherwise this just saved my life too.

Comment: This was great, thank you! Any idea why it worked in IE and FF but not Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and I found a very simple solution. Add the following parameter:

```
?wmode=transparent
```

to the youtube video url. For example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/brg1H4BuII8?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

More details [here](http://www.jenkaufman.com/youtube-iframe-embed-video-problem-hides-menus-other-layers-546/).

Answer (score 0):

This is building on @gregdev's answer:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  
transform: translateZ(0);
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

For complete browser support.